# ListBox flashing on horizontal scrolling when item selected

Tags: winapi, user32

I have a owner drawn ListBox and it's flicker free on resizing when done from dragging the parent window and when adding items and when vertical scrolling but when an item is selected and I try to horizontal scroll the item selected flickers really badly although none of the none selected ones do, how do I fix this or how do I detect when the scroll bar is selected to deselect the ListBox item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

http://www.catch22.net/tuts/flicker-free-drawing.

It outlines some things to try much better than I can...